# How to comparate two values of variables in Corona SDK

Tags: lua

I'm not able to compare two values ​​of variables in Corona SDK... HELP-ME PLEASE

Here is my code used to compare:

```
local bestscore = 0
local paraguardar = 0

local bestscore = display.newText(bestscore, 300, 0, nil, 30)
bestscore.isEditable = true
bestscore.bestscore = bestscore
bestscore.myName = bestscore

     local function HeMoved(event, tap)
          if event.phase == "began" then
          local object = event.target
          paraguardar = paraguardar + 1
          return false
         end
     end 

     local function Comparando()
        if(bestscore < paraguardar) then
         bestscore = paraguardar
         bestscore.text = paraguardar
       end

     end
```

After......

```
       Comparando()
```

I took only the parts that might be giving error ...

Help me, please

Answer (score 1):

You declared the 'bestscore' variable twice:

```
local bestscore = 0
...
local bestscore = display.newText(bestscore, 300, 0, nil, 30)
```

The 2nd declaration overrides the 1st one, so in Comparando

```
if(bestscore < paraguardar) then
```

You are comparing bestscore (an object/table) with paraguardar (a number).

The following change should fix the error, but I'm not sure that it's what you're really trying to do:

```
local function Comparando()
    if(bestscore.bestscore < paraguardar) then
     bestscore.bestscore = paraguardar
     bestscore.text = paraguardar
   end
end
```